# Add a value to a list in Firebase?

Tags: json, database, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I currently have a JSON object that is structured like this:

```
"users": {
    "0":
        {
        "items_list": {
            "0": [1],
            "1": [2,3],
            "2": [8, 9, 10],
            "3": [11, 12, 13]
            },
        "name": "Dana"
        }
    },
```

Upon pressing a button in a React-Native app, I want to add a value to the array of attributes stored for one of the keys in the items_list.

Specific example: Adding the number '14' to item '3', so that it will become "3": [11, 12, 13, 14].

Is there a way to just add a single value to an array without rewriting the whole thing? It seems like I may have to get the value of the array associated with a key, add a new value to it, and then push the whole thing back, but I wanted to check if there's a simpler way to go about doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To add an item to an array, you need to know how many items there already are in that array.

To know how many items are in a Firebase collection, you need to download those items (or keep a separate counter, but I'm going to ignore that for now).

This is one of the many reasons why the [Firebase documentation recommends against using an array to store collections of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase).

The [recommended solution is to use a so-called "push id"](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push), which are the very long cryptic looking values that are generated when your call [`ref.push()` in the Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html).

```
{
    "messages": {
        "-JhLeOlGIEjaIOFHR0xd": "Hello there!",
        "-JhQ76OEK_848CkIFhAq": "Push IDs are pretty magical.",
        "-JhQ7APk0UtyRTFO9-TS": "Look a white rabbit!"
    }
}
```

To learn more about what these push ids are, read [this blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html) explaining them.